# PayPal get exchange rate from transaction

Tags: php, api, paypal

With the PayPal API we get all our transactions with the API TransactionSearch and GetTransactionDetails. But the transacions are in the currency from the supplier (USD) and not in EUR.

Is there a way to get the exchange rate from the transaction with the PayPal API? I use Fixer.io but the rate is not the same as Paypal's rate.

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction request certainly have currency code

Find the code here and replace usd

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/currency_codes/